DMRG for anyons
I want to do some DMRG calculations for anyons. For example, consider the golden chain model for fibonacci anyons.
https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0612341
I have two anyon types: $1, \tau$. However, due to some constraints (the fusion rules), it turns out that the Hilbert space is constrained. In particular I cannot have two trivial anyons "next to each other" in a state.
eg. $|11\tau\rangle $ is not allowed.
This reduces the Hilbert space dimension from $2^L$ to $\phi^L$ for the fibonacci anyons ($\phi$ is the golden ratio).
My question is how do I translate this constrained Hilbert space to DMRG calculations?
My first guess is to "embed" the anyonic degrees of freedom to $\mathbb{Z}_N$ d.o.f.  For this case, we could say $1 = 1, \tau = 0$. We define the local hamiltonian (for fibonacci anyons a 3 site hamiltonian) to be a matrix of dimension $2^3\times2^3$. The "allowed" matrix elements are filled in according to the golden chain hamiltonian, and the matrix elements corresponding to states not allowed by the fusion rules are set to 0. I then put this into MPO format using singular value decompositions as normal. Would this method work? Would I also have to prepare the initial MPS so that the disallowed states have 0 coefficients?
Note: I understand that there have been new algorithms specifically for tensor networks for anyons. But to my knowledge DMRG calculations for these anyon models have been done since before these algorithms were introduced by modifying the original algorithm. I want to understand how this is done.

This seems like a non-trivial question.  If I understand correctly (but please correct me if I'm wrong) your Hilbert space doesn't have a tensor product structure. So the usual procedure of DMRG "adding a site..." doesn't work. MPS in this sense seems more versatile . There are several algorithms to optimize MPS.

How would you write a basis for the $L$ site Hilbert space?

@lcv Exactly, this problem doesn’t have a well defined local hilbert space. To write down a basis for L sites, I typically write down the full $2^L$ basis and go through and remove all the states that do not satisfy the constraints.

Consider to spell out acronyms.

I did some tests using ITensor and decided to answer my own question. Yes, embedding the anyonic degrees of freedom into spin degrees of freedom does seem to work (at least it appears to from the tests I have performed and comparing to results from exact diagonalization).
Editing my answer for anyone out there as lost as me. On running some more detailed tests, I found that I was not getting quite there. There were certain regions of my phase diagram where dmrg convergence was quite poor. You need to enforce the fusion rules by adding a potential term to the hamiltonian, which entails an energy penalty for violating the fusion rules. This can be done by simply adding a projector to the subspace that violates the fusion rules, and associating some positive energy cost. This gives better results.
